# How to check if query result is empty

Tags: javascript, sqlite, web-sql

```
tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM Routes WHERE id_object = 0", [], 
function (tx, result) 
{ 
alert('You already added'); 
},
function (tx, error) { 
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Routes (id_object) VALUES (0)');             
alert('add successfull')} ) 
}
```

If the result set of `SELECT * FROM Routes WHERE id_object = 0` is empty, it should execute `tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Routes (id_object) VALUES (0)');`

Answer (score 1):

Is the `id_object` unique (i.e., a primary key, or declared `UNIQUE`)? If so, you can simply

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Routes (id_object) VALUES (0);
```

If your `id_object` column cannot be made unique, then you need what's sometimes called an `UPSERT` (update or insert) statement. SQLite doesn't support this directly, but perhaps you can achieve it with a combination of triggers.

By far the easiest method is to do the test in your program's logic rather than in SQL, e.g., based on

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Routes WHERE id_object = 0"
```

and if the result is 0 do your insert.

Comment: tx.executeSql("SELECT Count(*) AS 'colvo' FROM Routes WHERE id_object = 0", [], function (tx, result) { if (result.rows['colvo'] == 0) alert('Вы уже добавляли данный объект ранее'); else {tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Routes (id_object) VALUES (0)'); }  },function (tx, error) { } )
Where is a bug?

Comment: Don't you need to use `result.rows.item(0).colvo == 0`? I am guessing at what programming language you are using. You need to look into the first row (which will be the only row) of the result set from the `select count(*)...`